# Mocking imported class in django unittest

Tags: python, django, mocking

I'm having issue's with setting up mocking for some django views.

backend.py

```
class Connector(object):
    def get_this():
        ...

    def get_that():
        ...
```

view_a.py

```
from backend import Connector

class AView(View):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        connector = Connector()
        things = connector.get_this(...)
```

view_b.py

```
class BView(View):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        connector = Connector()
        things = connector.get_that(...)
```

text_view_a.py

```
class ATest(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('backend.Connector')
    def test_simple(self, connector_mock):
        mi = mock.return_value  # The constructor
        mi.get_this.return_value = ...
        mi.get_that.return_value = ...
        response = self.client.get(
            reverse('...view_a'),
        )
        self.assertTrue(mi.get_this.called)
```

text_view_b.py

```
class BTest(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('backend.Connector')
    def test_simple(self, connector_mock):
        mi = mock.return_value  # The constructor
        mi.get_this.return_value = ...
        mi.get_that.return_value = ...
        response = self.client.get(
            reverse('...view_b'),
        )
        self.assertTrue(mi.get_that.called)
```

The behavior i'm seeing is that they all work fine individually but when running combined only the first succeeds and the rest fails. Basically it looks like only the first mock is setup/used. I guess this has something to do with the views taking their own copy of the imported class?

When is the best practice for mocking such backend classes?

Paul

Comment: I'm going to take a stab and say that your tests are not behaving idempotently. You should ensure that you are properly handling things in your setUp and tearDown based on how you are testing. Maybe you have something that is being kept at the class level that is affecting the instances of the class that you are not resetting each time?

Answer (score 4):

Just fixed it myself; i had to mock the class where it is used instead of where it came from....

```
class BTest(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('view_a.Connector')
    def test_simple(self, connector_mock):
        mi = mock.return_value  # The constructor
        mi.get_this.return_value = ...
        mi.get_that.return_value = ...
        response = self.client.get(
            reverse('...view_b'),
        )
        self.assertTrue(mi.get_that.called)
```

Comment: Maybe add some more code around how the solution should look like with reference to your code. It will help other people looking up this problem get to a speedier solution by seeing a more practical example of a solution